# WCF not sending type hint in message

Tags: c#, wcf

My service call isn't working and its because the type hinting isn't being sent along in the message.

Here's what is being sent.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <createLocalUser xmlns="http://adobe.com/idp/services">
            <localUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

And this is what it should be

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <createLocalUser xmlns="http://adobe.com/idp/services">
            <localUser i:type="UserImpl">
```

Notice the change on the localUser element. I know this is the problem because if I modify the request in fiddler, it works. I just don't know what to change in my C# code.

Here are my C# classes.

```
[DataContract(Name = "UserImpl", Namespace = NameSpace.Root)]
public partial class UserImpl : User { }

[DataContract(Name = "User", Namespace = NameSpace.Root)]
public partial class User : Principal { ... }

[DataContract(Name = "Principal", Namespace = NameSpace.Root)]
public partial class Principal { ... }
```

And the interface

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = NameSpace.Root)]
public interface IDirectoryManagementService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "createLocalUser")]
    string CreateLocalUser(DataContracts.UserImpl localUser, string password);
```

I think it's a problem with ServiceKnownType or KnownType, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. For anyone having the same issue, here is what made the difference.

My service interface was set to take a `UserImpl` object

```
string CreateLocalUser(DataContracts.UserImpl localUser, string password);
```

And I passed it a `UserImpl` instance. However, what I needed to do is change it to a `User` instead. Since `UserImpl` inherits from `User`, there isn't any issue for C#, but WCF notices the difference and adds the i:type attribute. So here is what I changed it too.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = NameSpace.Root)]
    public interface IDirectoryManagementService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "createLocalUser")]
        string CreateLocalUser(DataContracts.User localUser, string password);
```

Notice how localUser parameter is now a `User` type.